# Failure to push. Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, ssl, github

I am a new Git/GitHub Windows user. Using a fresh install of git and following a Lynda.com tutorial instructions, I have created the GitHub repo, generated the ssh, added the ssh key to my GitHub account,and authenticated the connection to GitHub.

When I try to push, I receive the error:

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

I have thoroughly perused StackOverflow and found similar questions, but I am unable to resolve a solution that works for me. I have posted the relevant git commands below. Any help is appreciated.

```
owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/PrinceHumperdinck/explore_california.git

owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ git remote
origin

owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PrinceHumperdinck/explore_california.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ ls -al ~/.ssh

total 18
drwxr-xr-x    1 owner    Administ        0 Aug  6 14:07 . 
drwxr-xr-x    1 owner    Administ    28672 Aug 10 11:57 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 owner    Administ     3326 Aug 10 10:51 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 owner    Administ      749 Aug 10 10:51 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 owner    Administ     1226 Aug  6 23:47 known_hosts

owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi PrinceHumperdinck! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents/explore_california (master)
$ git version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Praveen P for the quick response. I followed your suggestions and they  worked. With your generous help I successfully pushed to github. I will check out Sourcetree and Gitkraken and keep on pushing. Thanks again, you are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to access a Git-based source control service such as GitHub or GitLab, is through HTTPS or SSH. At the moment you're using the HTTPS method which requires you to authenticate every Fetch, Push or Pull request with your username and password. That's why you get this error.

> How to fix

Since you have added your SSH key to the GitHub account:

1. Goto the repository click "Clone or download"
2. Click "Use SSH" on the top right corner of the popup box. **ignore this step if it says *"Use HTTPS"***
3. Copy the link, it should look something like this `git@github.com:PrinceHumperdinck/explore_california.git`
4. Goin to the local copy (folder) and run this `git remote set-url ORIGIN git@github.com:PrinceHumperdinck/explore_california.git`. **Substitute ORIGIN with the value before the URL of this command `git remote -v`**
5. Run `git fetch` and if that works. Run `git push`.

If step 4 doesn't work for you, you can always clone it again with `git clone git@github.com:PrinceHumperdinck/explore_california.git`

Side note, if you're not familiar with command line GIT you can use GUI tools like [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) for free or [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) free for personal use (with annoying popup box)